# Menus: hiding left sidebar menu items, leaving main menu intact

Tags: module, menu

I'm fairly new to Joomla and have a site with some menu troubles. My header menu looks as follows

1. Menu1
2. Menu2
3. Menu3
4. Menu4
5. Menu5

Now I'm trying to set it up so that the menu across the top of the page displays all 5 elements. However, on the left side of the page, hides `Menu2`.

Under the `Left Menu` module, I selected `Exclude` under `Assignments` and selected the Menu2 element. However, it still appears on the page.

Am I misunderstanding how to hide elements of a menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the point of Menu Assignments. It's not a way to hide menu items, it's used to control **where a particular module will be displayed or hidden**. Based on the settings you mention above, if you click the `menu2` item, the `Left Menu` module will probably not be displayed.

If you want to hide a particular menu *item* from the left menu, the simplest way is to use CSS. Without any code it's hard to say exactly how, but you have to find a way to target *only* your `menu2` item, and hide it. Often, the menu items in Joomla uses the menu ID as class, and your HTML code could look something like this:

```
...
<li class="item132 ">
    <a class="item" href="/menu2">Menu 2 item</a>
</li>
...
```

If that's the case, you can hide the menu item by adding this line to your CSS code:

```
li.item132 { display:none; }
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! Definitely clarifies. However, simply using that CSS you listed would still hide it from both the top and side menu. I'd need to drill in even further and make it something like `#rt-sidebar-a.li.item132`, no?

Comment: That's right, you probably need to use a more specific selector. Use the code inspector (by clicking "F12" or right-click -> Inspect element) in your browser to find the best way to select one of the menus only.

Comment: Got it to work perfectly. I'll just drop this in my bucket of 'wouldn't it be nice if joomla...' things.